# set value for Model.Item after return data from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I send my request to controller by Ajax,
I want set data for Model.CustomerId when return data from controller by ajax .
and this is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var lall = $("#Bach").val();
        $("#Bach").change(function() {
            lall = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/DatesCheckLists/GetCustomerInfo',
                data: { id: lall },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#customerdata").text('');
                    $('#customerdata').text(data.Name + " " + data.LastName);
                  @Model.CustomerId = data.Id;  
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

when I run the project, get an error on

```
@Model.CustomerId = data.Id;
```

my error is

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Update: this is my Control

```
 public ActionResult GetCustomerInfo(string id)
    {
        var cu = db.DatesCustomers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == id);
        return Json(cu, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Which part gives error and can you post controller too please.

Comment: I don't have error from return value , i want set return value in razor view for Model.CustomerId and Update question

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You can just make an `hiddenfor` for this value and set it in `success` function to post if you want. You can change Model value only serverside, and use it to create views on clientside so. I can give an example to set a `hiddenfor` for customerId and post it then.

Comment: after return data from controller customer Id must change , the scenario , i get name and family by send code to controller and change txt name and family and the end i wand sync Model.CustomerId for send customerId by send in save button

Comment: Can you show us the view, please?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible, backing up what Lukas Kabrt said in the answer section.  However, if you use `@Html.` helpers which generate HTML on the client, you can change the `CustomerId` that way via ajax and jQuery.. but you CANNOT change the value of `CustomerId` that is initially loaded with the `Model`, which is what you're currently trying to do.  I can better explain in an answer if you allow us to observe your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a clientside hidden element to hold this id like

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
```

and on success function you can set it like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var lall = $("#Bach").val();
    $("#Bach").change(function() {
        lall = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/DatesCheckLists/GetCustomerInfo',
            data: { id: lall },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#customerdata").text('');
                $('#customerdata').text(data.Name + " " + data.LastName);
                $('#Id').val(data.Id); 
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

after that you can post it to controller and use it.

I don't think that you can directly update your Model from jquery. Model values is about serverside, declared on the serverside and Jquery is for manipulating the clientside. Another solution (A bad bad solution as T_Row explained why on comments )  is that to send `id` value to another controller that posts again with id updated model.

Comment: *Another solution is that to send id value to another controller that posts again with id updated model.*, that would require a page refresh which defeats the purpose of AJAX.. I think we need to see the view to get some clarity on what the OP is **really** trying to do

Comment: Because of that i didn't give any example about this method. It's a bad bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible. You are trying to mix two concepts - server-side view rendering a client side JavaScript.

`@Model.CustomerId = data.Id;` is evaluated on the server, when the view is rendered. It doesn't know anything about `data` variable introduced in the JS on client side (browser) when the AJAX call is made.

If you want to process `data.Id` further you can save it to a JS variable or to a hidden HTML field.